# Add image to cell and convert table to image

Tags: java, svg, batik

I have following CSV file, something like this

```
       Score   Result
1       1       Good       
2       0.8     Bad       
3       1       Good       
4       0.5     Bad        
5       0.3     Bad        
6       0.2     Bad
```

Depending upon the value of Result (Good or bad), I would like to replace the result with thumbs-down or thumbs up image and export the entire table to image.
Any pointers on how to do this in Java?

Comment: There are several ways you could go about this; I'd probably use [Apache Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/).